# Improve performance of QWebEngine offscreen rendering

Tags: qt, qt5, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

I want to use QWebEngine to render an animated webpage offscreen (with transparency). And I want to do it **fast** (e.g. 60 fps, which imposes ~16 ms maximum time per render).

This other SO question [Is it possible to render QWebEnginePage/QWebEngineView offscreen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53524652/is-it-possible-to-render-qwebenginepage-qwebengineview-offscreen) gives some hints:

- get a `QWebEngineView` with `Qt::WA_DontShowOnScreen` attribute
- get a `QPainter` on a `QImage` (with `QImage::Format_ARGB32`)
- call `QWidget::render()` on the said `QWebEngineView` instance

This works! But it's quite slow when the transparency (`QImage::Format_ARGB32`) is needed. By slow I mean >50-60 milliseconds per render on my machine (which is an equvalent of <20fps).

**The question is:** is there a faster, Qt-based alternative to rendering a webpage offscreen (to memory)?

Comment: be careful with the alternatives, as the page may contain some dynamic content